# Remove link image and other div IDs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
jQuery("#test").after("<a id='clearall' href='#' onclick='jQuery(this).remove(); jQuery('.clearselection').remove;'><img src='clearselection.gif'></a>");
```

When I try this, I get a syntax error:

```
jQuery(this).remove(); jQuery(<---
```

When I click the link, I need to remove the link image and remove all instances of that Class .clearselection. I tried escaping the single quotes, but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining the click handler inline use jquery to handle that:

```
$(document).on("click", "#clearall", function()
{
   jQuery(this).remove(); 
   jQuery('#clearselection').remove(); //btw you were missing the parens here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
onclick='jQuery(this).remove(); jQuery(\'.clearselection\').remove();'
```